# How to show just text inside an INPUT attribute? HTML

Tags: html, css

I do want to show just text inside an INPUT. So, How can I do it?

```
<p><input type="image" src="" border="0" name="submit" alt="Donate"></p>
```

Basically, It works good but Safari and Chrome does not display the `alt="Donate`. Instead, it shows an empty square.

**Edited:** 
I have used this code from bobince:

```
 <input type="submit" class="unbutton" value="Donate">

.unbutton {
    color: black; background: none;
    border: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;   /* this is an IE hack to avoid extra button width */
}
```

Then,  How can I display the word Donate? I do not want to use an images. I want to use just text to show Donate

PS: I am dealing with PayPal's donation button.

Answer: I have forgot to add `value="Donate"` :P

Comment: As per your update, do you realize that CSS should go in `<style>` or in a `.css` file which you include by `<link>`? The code works perfectly fine. You should probably provide more context.

Comment: Yes, I know how to declare CSS in HTML and/or <link> it as well. Thanks for you help, I think. I would do more research about inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's bad behaviour from WebKit that it doesn't show the `alt` text, but even so you shouldn't be deliberately using a broken image.

If all you want is a submit button without the button styling, you can do that with CSS:

```
<input type="submit" class="unbutton" value="Donate">

.unbutton {
    color: black; background: none;
    border: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;   /* this is an IE hack to avoid extra button width */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using `input type="image"`?

How about something like this:

```
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Donate"></p>
```

Comment: ...and if you *actually* want a background image, use CSS `background-image` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to be doing what you are doing here.  You are effectively making a dead image link here.

Rather than that, if you are trying to do a submit button or something, use the proper HTML type for this.